# Bitcoin programming on Raspberry Pi 4/Raspbian

Tags: c++, c, raspberry-pi, bitcoin, rust

I want to setup a *full* bitcoin node on a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspbian and make my own **local** requests in C/C++ (no client connection to a remote node).

**What would be the best library to do that ?**

Should I use another language ? (and what about Rust ?)

Comment: Should I use another language? Always. Single language programs are so boring. - that part of the question is highly subjective. It depends on your requirements. Why add a second language if you only want to make requests in C/C++?

Comment: And what about Rust? Rust exists. It can be used for programming. You want to learn Rust? Then do it. Otherwise, stick to C++. We can't answer that part of the question without knowing what you want.